# A criterion for commutative Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a Banach algebra and there exists $C>0$ such that $\|xy\| \leqslant C\|yx \|$ for all $x,y \in A$. I am trying to show that in this case $A$ is commutative. It is easy to show that given $x,y \in A$, the following inequality holds:
$$
\|\exp(-l x) \cdot y \cdot \exp(l x)\| \leqslant C\|y\|,
$$
for all $x,y \in A$, $l\in \mathbb{C}$, where $\exp(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$. Now I am trying to consider the function $f(l) = \varphi(\exp(-l x) \cdot y \cdot \exp(l x))$ for $\varphi \in A^*$. Then it seems that if $f$ is a bounded entire function, then (by Liouville theorem) it must be a constant, which gives the result, but I am stuck at this point. Can you please help me?

Comment: I suspect you mean $\exists C>0\; \forall x, y\;(\|x y\|\leq C\|y x\|).$ Where are you stuck? On showing that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: @user254665 Yes, that is correct. Basically, I don't know how to show that $f$ is an entire function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me it goes like so. Say $V$ is an open subset of $\Bbb C$ and $F:V\to A$. Define $F\in H(V,A)$ if $$F'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}$$exists for every $z\in V$. We could take various sorts of limits, in fact we can suppose that fraction converges in norm.

Exactly as in ordinary complex analysis you show that the sum of a convergent power series is holomorphic. So if $x\in A$ then the function $l\mapsto\exp(lx)$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C$.

And exactly as in ordinary  complex analysis, or for that matter exactly as in Calc I, you show that the product of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic. So if you define $$F(l)=\exp(-lx)y\exp(lx)$$then $F\in H(\Bbb C,A)$. The inequality in your post shows that $||F(l)||\le C||y||$ for every $l$.

So the question is to show Liouville works for $A$-valued holomorphic functions. It's easy to show from the definition that $F$ holomorphic implies that $\phi\circ F$ is holomorphic for $\phi\in A^*$. So Liouville implies $\phi\circ F$ is constant. Now Hahn-Banach implies that $F$ is constant.

(Hence $\exp(x)y=y\exp(x)$ for every $x$. Now if $z\in A$ there exists $a>0$ so $||az||<1$. The power series for $\log(1-t)$ in the unit disk shows that there exists $x$ with $1-az=\exp(x)$. Hence $(\Bbb 1-az)y=y(\Bbb 1-az)$, and hence $yz=zy$.)

Comment: Sorry, did not get the last implication: how do we get $xy=yx$ for all $x\in A$ from the fact that $xy=yx$ for all $x$ with $\|1-x\| <1$? And why do we write $\|1-x\| < 1$ instead of just $\|x\| < 1$?

Comment: @kissanpentu ??? How do _you_ get the conclusion from the fact that $F=y$? You said if you showed that you were done... I assumed you knew how to do this, hence the parentheses. Anyway, I just fixed a typo and added a little detail to the answer.

Comment: @kissanpentu Yesterday I thought I'd edited the thing inserting more detail at the end. Somehow the edit didn't appear - re-edited just now...